# Using XPath Functions to Clear Unnecessary Information

Tags: xpath

We have a result from an XML sync that comes in like this:

```
<items>
  </item>
    <extension_attributes>
      <coaf type="string">{"additional_fields":{"attribute_id":"425","attribute_code":"last_4_digits","admin_label":"Last 4 Digits","label":"Last 4 Digits","email":"1","pdf":"0","value":"4321"},"which_warehouse":{"attribute_id":"426","attribute_code":"which_warehouse","admin_label":"Warehouse Location","label":"Which Warehouse (Assuming Available Stock)","email":"1","pdf":"0","value":"Either or"}}</coaf>
    </extension_attributes>
  </item>
</items>
```

I believe (and have asked, but they only answered with an assumption as well) that we are using XPath 1.0

To get the Match and load the fields, I have set:

```
/root/items/item/extension_attributes/coaf
```

And within the value field, I have placed something like a simple translate to make sure all is being found correctly:

```
translate(/root/items/item/extension_attributes/coaf, 'attribute_code{}"attribute_id','')
```

Which obviously comes back with a pretty crazy result (to be expected) like:

```
nlfls::425,:ls4gs,mnll:Ls 4 Dgs,ll:Ls 4 Dgs,ml:1,pf:0,vl:4321,whhwhs::426,:whhwhs,mnll:Whs Ln,ll:Whh Whs (Assmng Avll Sk),ml:1,pf:0,vl:Eh
```

So we are sure we are in the right place, just unsure how to attack this.

We have tried replace, but unsure how to combine replace commands together to get rid of the extra information, especially because the value field within this program we are using is (currently) limited to 100 characters. So a lengthy replace line to get all the extra information would likely go over the character count.

What would be the best way to shed all the unnecessary information and essentially just retain the important fields like only keeping label:title1 & value:value1 and label:title2 & value:value2 ?

Comment: Can you tell us what's your expected output from the above sample.

Comment: Absolutely! Ideally with the given sample, we would like the output to be something like:  Last 4 Digits : 4321, Which Warehouse (Assuming Available Stock) : Either or -- where it is just taking the 'label' field and 'value' field for each given part of the array

Comment: Under, `coaf` how many label:value you gonna have, is it always 2, as in the above example or is it dynamic?

Comment: It would be dynamic in that we can add more fields if we so choose (or remove some), so as more coaf fields enter the array, we would need to alter the XPath to account for this if need be. Currently at this time, it would be 2

Comment: You haven't told us whether it's XPath 1.0 or 2.0+. For string manipulation in XPath, you really need 2.0+. If you only have 1.0, it's best to return the data to the host application and manipulate it there.

Comment: I will trust in that it is probably XPath 1.0, but for arguments sake and the continuation of this thread, I will say it is XPath 2.0. (and press on them to try and update their deployed XPath versions)

Comment: They got back to me and stated they can't upgrade from XPath 1.0 to XPath 2.0 because "Microsoft's framework doesn't support XPath 2.0", is this true? and does this make what I am trying to accomplish nearly impossible now?